# Cordova Build Failing

Tags: android, cordova

Hello I am attempting to set up a cordova environment on ubuntu 16.04, I have android studio installed, and what I beleave are all the dependanceys installed, but when I run cordova build I get the following error, Could someone help with what dependancy I am missing?

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/fast/html/slim_phone/slimapps/platforms/android/CordovaLib/cordova.gradle' line: 64

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

But I have Android build tools 19.1.0 installed and 25.0

```
#/fast/home/tholum/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --list
Installed packages:
  Path                        | Version | Description                    | Location                    
  -------                     | ------- | -------                        | -------                     
  build-tools;19.1.0          | 19.1.0  | Android SDK Build-Tools 19.1   | build-tools/19.1.0/         
  build-tools;25.0.3          | 25.0.3  | Android SDK Build-Tools 25.0.3 | build-tools/25.0.3/         
  emulator                    | 26.0.3  | Android Emulator               | emulator/                   
  extras;android;m2repository | 47.0.0  | Android Support Repository     | extras/android/m2repository/
  extras;google;m2repository  | 51      | Google Repository              | extras/google/m2repository/ 
  patcher;v4                  | 1       | SDK Patch Applier v4           | patcher/v4/                 
  platform-tools              | 25.0.6  | Android SDK Platform-Tools     | platform-tools/             
  platforms;android-25        | 3       | Android SDK Platform 25        | platforms/android-25/       
  sources;android-25          | 1       | Sources for Android 25         | sources/android-25/         
  tools                       | 26.0.2  | Android SDK Tools              | tools/
```

Comment: I figured it out after looking into it, My ANDROID_HOME was set to the wrong directory, I had it in the Sdk/tools instead of just the Sdk/

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with my ANDROID_HOME

It was

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/home/tholum/Android/Sdk/tools"
```

and should have been

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/home/tholum/Android/Sdk/"
```